# ASP.NET MVC localizing Annotation resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, annotations, resources

Using Griffin.MvcContrib I already managed to localize the The '{0}' field is required Message but I have problems localizing " Email is already taken " message, so the question would be where this message is located? for my previous problem the resource name was Required and the value was The '{0}' field is required, but for email validation problem I mentioned I don't know the resource and it's name and value parameters.

Comment: Anybody out there to help on this problem?

Comment: Maybe we need a bit more context. Source code, etc.